# Why does max doesn't work in CGFloat extension in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

Anybody knows what this doesn't work (Static member min cannot be used on instance of Type CGFloat. in the extension.

```
extension CGFloat {
    mutating func normalize() {
        self = min(max(CGFloat(0), self), CGFloat(1))
   }
}
```

while this works

```
let f: CGFloat = CGFloat(0.4)
let maxValue = max(f, 1)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get this to work by specifying Swift.min and Swift.max as such:

```
extension CGFloat {
    mutating func normalize() {
        self = Swift.min( Swift.max(CGFloat(0), self), CGFloat(1))
    }
}
```

when using just min and max it is unsure if you mean CGFloat.min or Swift.min